# "time" command in Cygwin works, but not in NetBean

Tags: netbeans, time, command, cygwin

I can do this in Cygwin, adding `time` Command

```
USER@USER_PC ~
$ time ./HelloWorld
```

shows smthing like

```
Hello World!!!
real    0m0.270s
user    0m0.270s
sys     0m0.270s
```

I've deployed an similar C/C++ Project @NetBean7.2 @Win 7.

It shows error message at Run time,  Only when I add `time` Command ,like:

```
time "${OUTPUT_PATH}"
```

,at the Text Field of *`Projcet_file-> R_Click -> Properties -> Run -> Run_Command:`*

,and default value `${OUTPUT_PATH}` only.

Error message is

```
C:\ProjectFolder\time does not exist or is not an executable
```

,seems that NetBean consider `time` as an excutable

Any better ways to solve it??

Comment: Also, some says there's no such a file `time.exe` in `cygwin/usr/bin` directory. `time` command in Cygwin might link to some exe of Win7. This might be helpful to this Prob.

Answer (score 1):

full command to bash needs to be in quotes if calling from cmd shell

```
bash -c "time ls"
```

Answer (score 0):

*time* is a builtin command of *bash*. On my cygwin installation the proper command is:

```
c:\cygwin\bin\bash -c time
```

You have to adjust the path to bash.

Comment: Do you mean add `c:\cygwin\bin\bash` to NetBean Project Properties?
Or to System Variable?
If to Netbean, where may i add this path to?

Comment: `bash` is the command you want to run and `-c time` are command line parameters. There is no solitary time command, it's a function built into bash.

Comment: Thank you. This helps me know more about bash.
But i still cannot realize "time" my program.
I tried `c:\cygwin\bin\bash -c time "${OUTPUT_PATH}" ` on Netbean.

It seems that it can run only one exe file , in this case is bash.exe, not my main.exe

Comment: I think it's close to the solution...

My Question Becomes like:
i have 
Helloworld.exe and bash.exe in `c:\cygwin\bin\`

How can time HelloWorld.exe in Win7 command line???

Comment: Try `c:\cygwin\bin\bash -c time /bin/HelloWorld.exe`

Comment: Not Work. only `bash.exe` is launched,
not `HelloWorld.exe`.

Even i put `bash -c time` shows same output
real 0m0.004s
user 0m0.000s
sys  0m0.000s